# Wait for AFNetworking operation for login

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2

I have an app that needs to use AFNetworking and I'm having an issue with the operations being asynchronous. I know there are a lot of similar questions here, but I have not found the answer to my issue yet.

The app calls a login method in - `(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

That method looks like this:

```
- (void)loginWithUsername:(NSString *)username password:(NSString *)password {
    url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"Users/Login/" relativeToURL:baseURL];
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{UsernameParameter: username, PasswordParameter: password};
    [requestManager GET:url.absoluteString parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        user = [[User alloc] initWithServerResponse:responseObject];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(error.description);
    }];
}
```

The response contains a couple of authorization tokens that are necessary for all other calls to the remote API. The problem is that the other operations are being executed before the login response is received and the success or failure blocks are executed. As a result, the app is crashing (or does nothing if I check for a nil user) when it tries to make another call to the API. What is the best way to ensure that the login response is received before proceeding?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do the another calling of remote api after user's login call  (in the block).
e.g.

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{UsernameParameter: username, PasswordParameter: password};
[requestManager GET:url.absoluteString parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    user = [[User alloc] initWithServerResponse:responseObject];
    ///insert another remote api here.

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(error.description);

   ///warnning for error.
}];
```

Comment: I decided to try that again right before I saw your suggestion. This seems to do the trick. It didn't work the first time I tried so I must have had an error the first time. Thank you.